# Existence of integer solution to 63x+70y+15z=2010

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have an equation $63x+70y+15z=2010$. The question asks me to conclude whether it has an integral solution or not?  Any help on how to proceed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solving the equation certainly gives an affirmative answer.

$$
z=\frac{-21x}{5}+\frac{-14y}{3}+134,
$$
hence
the  solution in integers is $x=5n$, $y=3m$, $z=-21n-14m+134$, where $n$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 6):

The gcd of the coefficients is $1$. In particular, it divides $2010$, so there is an integer solution.

If we want to look more closely, we can see that for example we can take $x=0$. The equation $70y+15z=2010$ has a solution, since the gcd of $70$ and $15$ divides $2010$.

Comment: How did you get such a condition.Can you share any articles in this regard or any books.Looking forward to you

Comment: It is a standard early result in number theory (almost any book) that the congruence $ax+by=c$ has an integer olution if and only if the gcd of $a$ and $$b$ divides $c$. This can be extended by induction to several variables.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the equation mod $3,5$ and $7$, we get: $x=5p, y=3q, z=7r+1$ where $p,q,r\in\mathbb Z$. Putting these back into the original equation, we get $3p+2q+r=19$ which is much easier to solve. $(0,0,134),(30,0,8),(0,27,8)$ etc. are all solutions.