# An equation of three variables has integral solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The  given  equation  is $63x+70y+15z=2010$  and  I  have  to  whether  it  has  any  integral  solution   and  if  yes  what  that  is .

Now  this  is  one  equation  in  $3$  variables  . How  can  I  tell  there  are  integral  solutions . How  to  approach?

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: a start would be to check if 63, 70 or 15 divides 2010...if any of them do, why is that helpful? also, for a general answer, the key is division.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000790/existence-of-integer-solution-to-63x70y15z-2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** This question is equivalent to determining whether $63x + 70y = 2010 \pmod{15}$ has a solution, which is in turn equivalent to $3x + 10y = 0 \pmod{15}$.

Comment: So$\ $ $15$  divides $3x+10y$ . $15=3\times 5$ . So make  $x$  a  multiple  of  $5$  and  $y$  a  multiple  of  $3$  and  hence  the  solution. Am  I  correct?

Comment: Yes. With a bit of extra work you can even show that this yields all the solutions to the equation.

Comment: Sorry  but is  not  that  $9x+10y\equiv 2010(\mod 15)$?

Comment: $63 = 4\cdot15 + 3$, so $63 = 3 \pmod{15}$.